# Hibernated HDD from one Windows installation to another

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, hibernate

I have a HDD full of data from my old Windows 10 installation which I want to connect to a new installation (still Windows 10), however I realized that the HDD is in a hibernation state due to me not fully shutting down Windows before reinstalling (my mistake).

My question is: if I connect the "hibernated" HDD to a new Windows 10 installation, what will happen? Is there any danger that the data will be lost / corrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hibernation is simply a way of storing the RAM content into the hiberfil.sys located on the hibernated drive - you can safely connect it to your new Windows 10 installation to retrieve any data you need.